Вживання слова м'язевий
В статті Українська медична мова: проблеми та їх вирішення - вказується, що вживати слово м'язевий - неправильно.



Правильно
Неправильно




М’язовий
М’язевий



Хоча в словнику https://goroh.pp.ua/Словозміна/м'язевий - це слово присутнє.
Чи існує таке слово?

Так, істнуєʼ, але не в стандартій українській мові.
Заміна о → е відбуваєʼся зазвичай після с/палаталізованих звуків — досить поширене явище для словʼянських мов.  Але стандартна українська тут не дуже послїдовна, пак гинколи зміни ідуть дальше і цїкавіше: єї → йийі → її, але при цьому його.
Втім тут проблема насамперед не в цьому. Просто українській відомі записи як [за стандартом] мʼяз [тому і мʼязовий] і мʼязь [тож очїкувано мʼязевий]. Про всяк зазначу, що мʼязь — жїночого роду:

Др. Степан Балей : Нарис психольоґії (1922), 135 с.
повільна мязь


Прикметникові суфікси -ев, -ов

Суфікс -ов-(ий) незалежно від наголосу вживаємо у прикметниках, що
мають перед цим суфіксом букву, яка передає твердий приголосний



М'язовий спазм
М'язовий тонус

Докину ще свій п'ятак до десятки.
Запустив пошук по ВЕСУМ на *зевий і ось що отримав:

багатогалузевий adj:m:v_naz
бязевий adj:m:v_naz
внутрігалузевий adj:m:v_naz:bad
внутрішньогалузевий adj:m:v_naz
вузькогалузевий adj:m:v_naz
галузевий adj:m:v_naz
грязевий adj:m:v_naz:bad
ґедзевий adj:m:v_naz
загальногалузевий adj:m:v_naz
зовнішньогалузевий adj:m:v_naz
квазігалузевий adj:m:v_naz
макрогалузевий adj:m:v_naz
міжгалузевий adj:m:v_naz
моногалузевий adj:m:v_naz
нарізевий adj:m:v_naz
негалузевий adj:m:v_naz
одногалузевий adj:m:v_naz
підгалузевий adj:m:v_naz
позагалузевий adj:m:v_naz
різногалузевий adj:m:v_naz
середньогалузевий adj:m:v_naz
територіально-галузевий adj:m:v_naz
ферзевий adj:m:v_naz

А ось і первинні слова, від яких ці слова походять:

*галузь
бязь
ґедзь
нарізь
ферзь

Як бачимо, всі ці слова мають наприкінці м'яку з, що підтверджує інші відповіді.
